# how to allow public traffic only through domain in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I have an ec2 instance which is open to public access with ip address. I have now connected a domain with it and want to use that domain only. I need to block access to ip. I tried changing security groups but no luck.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Basically my instance was hacked and db was deleted. Luckily it was a home project and this is a test server. There fore i was looking for a solution to save myself from these attacks. I asked my senior and he told me to do this.

Comment: You may have misunderstood what was asked. I would go back and clarify what you have been asked to do and ask how it will solve whatever problem it is designed to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to block access by hostname by using security groups, these simply function as a whitelist for incoming IP addresses.

You have 2 solutions that can be used to allow this functionality:

- The first solution would be to add a secondary host configuration in your web server (apache, NGINX) to have your web site domain. Have the first host (or default host) return a 403 if any user attempts to access on that page.
- The second solution would be to add either CloudFront or a load balancer in front of your application. You could then add a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) with a default block policy. It would only allow traffic through if the "Host" header matched the name of your site.